# How to create forms using a texture?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask, texture, clipping-mask

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.digitalartsonline.co.uk/tutorials/photoshop/create-abstract-poster-effects/?pn=3) and have reached the 8th step. I cannot understand how the author has placed the texture over the shapes and he has done it in multiple different ways.

Can someone help me out?

[image]

Here's what I have done so far:

I have made a selection using the polygonal lasso tool, made a new layer for the fill, made the fill and then placed the texture over it using the clipping mask.

The tutorial does not go into much detail of how it is done, but if anyone can suggest an alternate method also that would be nice.

I would like to learn as much as I can through this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain what you ware trying to do a bit more clearly? I'm sorry, but I'm not going to watch an off-site tutorial to answer your question ;)

Comment: The tutorial doesn't go into much detail and only says "Use the Polygonal Lasso tool, to make forms using the texture." - I'd be tempted instead to make a vector mask for the texture image.   What have you tried?

Comment: That's what I did also. I made a selection using the polygonal lasso tool, gave it a fill, and made a layer mask over that fill to put in the texture.

I'd post my image here but I am unable to do so.

Comment: @user3409468 Post your attempt on imgur(dot)com and share the link here, and someone here will add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is telling you to use the Polygonal Lasso Tool to "trace out" segments from that texture to match the shapes you created in the previous steps as well as other shapes to act as accents.

[image]

[image]

Sadly this is part of the tutorial that you can't just follow steps, which is good because it starts to force you to experiment on your own and not just copy verbatim.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark this as an answer.